# Ошибка при использовании функции-фильтра

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Следующий код

```
void BaseMode::slotCreatePreviousImageLoader() {
if (currentIndex_ > 0) {
    QFileInfoList::const_iterator begin = passageFileList_.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < previousPosIndex_; ++i) {
        ++begin;
    }
    QFileInfoList::const_iterator end = begin;
    ++end;
    if (begin != end) {
        QFuture<QFileInfo> filterFuture = QtConcurrent::filtered(begin, end, filterCheckAttribute);
    }
}

bool BaseMode::filterCheckAttribute(const QFileInfo& file) {
return true;
```

}

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

> argument of type 'bool (BaseMode::)(const QFileInfo&)' does not match 'bool (BaseMode::*)(const QFileInfo&)'

Как исправить?

Пример из документации:

```
bool allLowerCase(const QString &string)
{
    return string.lowered() == string;
}

QStringList strings = ...;
QFuture<QString> lowerCaseStrings = QtConcurrent::filtered(strings, allLowerCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток! 
Для того чтобы Ваш код заработал необходимо сделать функцию `filterCheckAttribute` либо статической, либо глобальной. Вот работающий пример со статической функцией:

```
//basemode.h
#pragma once
#include <QObject>

class QFileInfo;
class BaseMode :
    public QObject
{
public:
    BaseMode();
    ~BaseMode();
public slots:
    void slotCreatePreviousImageLoader();
    static bool filterCheckAttribute(const QFileInfo& file);
};

// basemode.cpp
#include "basemode.h"
#include <QFuture>
#include <QDir>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QtConcurrentFilter>
BaseMode::BaseMode(){}

BaseMode::~BaseMode(){}

void BaseMode::slotCreatePreviousImageLoader() 
{
    QDir dir = QDir::current();
    QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files);
    QFuture<QFileInfo> filterFuture = 
        QtConcurrent::filtered(list.begin(), list.end(), &BaseMode::filterCheckAttribute);
}

bool BaseMode::filterCheckAttribute(const QFileInfo& file) {
    return true;
}
```